# Dns has a bunch of records pointing to itself - how to change a-record without taking down email?

Tags: email, dns, cpanel

SO I went to put a new website live and got into my clients cpanel to change the a-record for the website - however it's a really weird set up - most of the records point back to the domain itself - and I know that changing the a-record will stop their email dead.

The first a-record points to a IP address - `domainname.com - 111.222.333.444`

A cname record: `www.domainname.com points to domainname.com`

A cname record: `mail.domainname.com points to domainname.com`

Then there's a text record (`domainname.com`) with the record:  `v=spf1 a mx ptr include:rhostbh.com ?all`

Finally, in a different part of c-panel, there's the mx record that points to: `domainame.com`

Then there's a bunch more records that point to the same IP address as before, such as autoconfig.domainname.com and autodiscover.doamainname.com.

So the question is, how do I change the main a-records (`domainname.com` and `www.domainname.com` putting the new site live) without taking out the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete `mail.domainname.com CNAME`
2. Create A record: 
   `mail.domainname.com A 111.222.233.244`
3. Modify MX to point to `mail.domainname.com`
4. Wait for TTL to expire
5. Modify `domainname.com` as required